# Chrome not rendering space unicode glyph

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, whitespace, font-face

I'm working on a project that requires using a single glyph font to replace the space (unicode 0020) in flow text with a special character. I've got this working beautifully in IE9+, Firefox and Safari, but Chrome is not behaving. Opera looks the same as Chrome but I don't have to support it.

I have a webfont, made using Font Squirrel in the usual way, which just defines unicode 0020 (the space) and I use it in a stack like this:

```
font-family:'My Replacement Space', arial, sans-serif;
```

In all the browsers that work, the space is replaced and all the other characters are rendered using arial (or sans-serif) as a fallback. In Chrome, Arial is used throughout and the spaces remain blank.

Anyone recall anything buggy relating to Chrome and something like this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this post on SU help: http://superuser.com/questions/232636/displaying-unicode-on-chrome-vs-firefox